# Implementing IMessageFilter in VB.Net console application

Tags: vb.net

Using sample code snippets obtained during my research, I am trying to implement the IMessageFilter interface in VS 2017 in a VB.Net console application. The code below is the relevant part of a larger project. My test suite involves a compiled AutoHotkey app which sends the WM_COPYDATA message and the built version of the VB code is meant to trap this message. A further test AutoHotkey app was also created to trap the sent message and this works successfully. So, the problem is with the VB code.

I have chosen not to trap the windows message by overriding WndProc since no form is being created in the console application. The idea is simply to catch the incoming message which then will cause other code to check environment variables set by the sending AHK app. The VB code below builds successfully and the exe file is run from a command in the AHK app which later sends the WM_COPYDATA message when a hotkey is pressed.

The code writes the received environment variable correctly but does not write anything relating to the sent windows message.

Having implemented the IMessageInterface with the myFilter class, I believe the only steps to be taken in Main() are to instantiate that class and to pass the new object as a parameter with Application.AddMessageFilter(). Since the Logger.txt file does not update after recording the environment variable, I am obviously missing something. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

You can test the compiled VB app by using any other app to send to it any Windows message.

Code:

```
' The Imports section contains statements which are relevant to other code 
' not shown here


Imports System
Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Environment
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security


Module Module1

Public Const WM_COPYDATA As Integer = &H4A
Public logger As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("logger.txt")

Sub Main()
    Dim EnvString As String
    EnvString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("masterHandle")
    logger.WriteLine("Master handle is {0}", EnvString)

    Dim msgFilter As myFilter
    msgFilter = New myFilter()
    Application.AddMessageFilter(msgFilter)
    Dim MSGFLT_ALLOW As Long = 1
    ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, WM_COPYDATA, MSGFLT_ALLOW, Nothing)

    Console.ReadKey()
    logger.Close()
End Sub

Public Class myFilter
    Implements IMessageFilter
    Public Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message) _
    As Boolean Implements IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage
        logger.WriteLine("New message received")
        If (m.Msg = WM_COPYDATA) Then
            logger.WriteLine("CopyData message received")
        End If
        Return False
    End Function
End Class

<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Public Function ChangeWindowMessageFilter(ByVal message As Long, ByVal dwFlag As Long) As Boolean
End Function

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the actual task you are trying to solve? Which application will send the WM_COPYDATA?

Otherwise, just some generic Googling revealed:

> Starting with Windows Vista, the application that is to receive the WM_COPYDATA message must call the ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx function.  Otherwise the the message will not be received.  It will be blocked by UIPI.
>
> For example, in an MFC application, you might add this code to the frame's OnCreate handler:

```
BOOL rc = ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx(m_hWnd, WM_COPYDATA, MSGFLT_ALLOW, NULL);
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011(v=vs.85).aspx